# Python Spark na.fill does not work

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

I'm working with spark 1.6 and Python.
I merged 2 dataframe:
`df = df_1.join(df_2, df_1.id == df_2.id, 'left').drop(df_2.id)`

I get new data frame with correct value and "Null" when the key don't match.
I would like to replace all "Null" values in my dataframe.

I used this function but it does not replace null value:
`new_df = df.na.fill(0.0)`

Does someone know why it does not work?

Many thanks for your answer.

Comment: Are you sure the data is not a string that says 'Null'?

Comment: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The issue is solved, the filed which contains null value was not float.